# Kubectl port-forward not working with IBM Cluster

Tags: kubernetes, ibm-cloud

When I do Kubernetes port-forward with IBM cluster I get connection refused. I have access to other clusters like Azure Kubernetes Service and kubectl port-forward is working fine there. Also when I get a pod log using `kubectl logs {pod_name}` I get TLS handshake error but the other kubernetes commands like get pod and describe pod is working fine.

Comment: I'm not familiar with IBM clusters, but I've seen this error when the kube-proxy isn't installed there. Could you run "kubectl get pods --all-namespaces|grep proxy" to see if there is any pod running? Also I had that problem because my kubeconfig was wrong, so I've deleted it and created a new one.

Comment: There are different options to deploying Kubernetes in IBM Cloud (Classic, VPC, OpenShift, ...). Please add details on your environment. There is also this FAQ entry which might help: https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/containers?topic=containers-ts_clis#exec_logs_fail

Comment: We are using Classic Infrastructure in our cluster.

Comment: I also tried deleting the proxy pod but I still get the TLS handshake error.

Comment: What K8s version is your cluster? Are you also having issues w/`kubectl exec`?